# pip3 install isal fails in Ubuntu 18 but works fine in Ubuntu 20 (dockerized scenario)

Tags: python, docker, ubuntu, pip

I would greatly appreciate help in tackling a problem that drives me crazy (I do need **Ubuntu 18.04** and python 3). I did try using different scenarios, but everything fails when installing PyPI package [isal](https://pypi.org/project/isal/) on Ubuntu 18.04:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y
RUN apt install -y python3 python3-pip 
RUN pip3 install isal
```

`docker build .`  fails with:

```
Step 3/3 : RUN pip3 install isal
 ---> Running in 71a47c31d97c
Collecting isal
  Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d6/72/b997fd8ba95a0820edcd5da268505705a5518fd860d64bf28a7c1c343a3a/isal-0.11.0.tar.gz (680kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: isal
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for isal: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for isal: finished with status 'error'
  ....
  running build_ext
  /tmp/tmpk3o08f96/autogen.sh: 3: /tmp/tmpk3o08f96/autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found
  error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpk3o08f96/configure': '/tmp/tmpk3o08f96/configure'
  
  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for isal
  Running setup.py clean for isal
Failed to build isal
Installing collected packages: isal
  Running setup.py install for isal: started
    Running setup.py install for isal: finished with status 'error'
    Complete output from command /usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qa68yevk/isal/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8qioc11y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    /usr/lib/python3.6/distutils/dist.py:261: UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'long_description_content_type'
      warnings.warn(msg)
    ....
    running build_ext
    /tmp/tmpnfxsy9ug/autogen.sh: 3: /tmp/tmpnfxsy9ug/autogen.sh: autoreconf: not found
    error: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpnfxsy9ug/configure': '/tmp/tmpnfxsy9ug/configure'
    
    ----------------------------------------
Command "/usr/bin/python3 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-qa68yevk/isal/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-8qioc11y-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-qa68yevk/isal/
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install isal' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

while FROM ubuntu:20.04 everything works fine

pip also fails:

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04
RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y \
&& apt install -y python python-pip 
RUN pip install isal

Step 3/3 : RUN pip install isal
 ---> Running in 6e157d7d965a
Collecting isal
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement isal (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for isal
The command '/bin/sh -c pip install isal' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

you can try `apt install autoconf` to resolve `autoreconf: not found`